# videoview not showing on device nor xml design,

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

I am new in java and xml programming, i am making tabbed activity with fragment, there is no error when running or debug the code but VideoView is not showing, i am using Android Studio, 
the idea is i want to make tabbed activity, with textView and videoview in fragment as a content that scrollable(possible ?),one more thing is the API level somehow have influence ? my phone still on KitKat
here is the (fragment) code :

```
package com.panduanberwudhu;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MencuciTangan extends Fragment {

private VideoView player;
private String videopath;
private MediaController mediacon;
public  View rootView;

//@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mencucitangan_layout, container, false);
    mediacon = new MediaController(getActivity());

    player = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
    videopath = "android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.washhand;
    player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videopath));
    player.setMediaController(mediacon);
    mediacon.setAnchorView(player);
    player.start();

    return rootView;
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mencucitangan_layout,container,false);
    }
}
```

and the layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mencucitangan_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.panduanberwudhu.MencuciTangan">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            />

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your `TextView` is covering the whole layout due to `match_parent` attributes.

Comment: keep    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  and check once

Comment: tried it, i edit the textview width and height still not working, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this layout, where the height `Relativelayout` is `wrap_content` which will increase/wrap according to content because it is inside the `ScrollView` .

I removed `Linearlayout` as hard coded some value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mencucitangan_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:id="@+id/ap"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/videoplayer" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Output:

[image]